# How to get info if I am in village or out of the village (city)? (iOS geocoder or Overpass API for OSM)

Tags: geocoding, core-location, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, overpass-api

Is there any way to find out if I am within village/city or out the village/city using iOS SDK (geocoder information) or Overpass API for OSM?

I know there are commercially APIs providing this feature, but I am wondering if it exists any API or service for free? I am working on pseudo-navigation app and I need this info about my current location.

Edit: For now I am using geocoding - placemark info about location - if thouroughfare is null or some number (street or road No.) - I am out the town. If there is some 'string' - it is street name and I am in the city. But this approach is very inaccurate. I am also considering using Overpass API for Open Street Maps and I am wondering if OSM provides such information. Thanks for any sugestions.

Thank you

Comment: if you know the center of the village and approximate size it's a simple distance check between the center and current location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS location services provide information about the device's position, but not information about the context of the position, such as which city they are near and how close they are to it. Geographic data such as what you're interested in comes at a price, which is why there are commercial SDKs providing it.